# Bind Textbox To a Field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a form in MS access. I have created a few textboxs in that form. I have input a function in the control source property of a particular textbox(TOTAL). This basically sums up numbers entered by the user and displays it in the textbox.

The problem is the textbox is unbound. I want to bind the textbox to a field in the table using vba code. I could have just bind the textbox by the putting the table field name in the control source property but it is occupied with the SUM() function.

I not sure how to proceed here. I have tried searching up on the web for several days but failed to gather a reasonale solution.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the sum function and put that in a suitable event for the form or event for another control and then bind the textbox.

As a general rule, you should not be storing calculated values, it is against the rules for normalization.

Comment: Yes i agree with you. But my boss requires me to do store the calculated values.

Comment: Get another boss :) Use an event to update the bound control with the sum, as I say above.